# How to estimate power consumption of an Android app? Is it linear?

Tags: android

I do a few of experiments and find I can't estimate power consumption of an app.

e.g.: I find it is *100mW* when I just run my app, and it is *20mW* when I do nothing. I think *80mW* is consumed by my app. But it is *200mW* I run another app B and my app also run, and it is *160mW* when I just run app B, so my app also consume *40mW*? Which one is correct?

In my eyes, it relate to CPU load rate, or something other I don't know. So we can not estimate power consumption by subtraction because it's not linear. So I want to know how to estimate power consumption correctly?

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how fine grained up power consumption you're looking for, but I can tell you a good rule of thumb for keeping power usage to a minimum: only use the radios when necessary. The bulk of power usage from your app is going to be from using the GPS and network radios. If you can keep those to a minimum, you're app is just going to take dainty little sips of power like it's drinking tea at a cricket match.

Comment: Thank you very much. "only use the radios when necessary" this sentence give me a inspiration. So if I keep other power usage to a minimum, may I just do a subtraction or should I consider these power usage(include radios) be my app's. I'm in favor of the latter.

Comment: Yea, you need to consider radio usage as part of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at PowerTutor

> PowerTutor is an application for Google phones that displays the power consumed by major system components such as CPU, network interface, display, and GPS receiver and different applications

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank for your advice. I installed this app but I think it may not provide accuracy I need.

Comment: Then use the [Trepn profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/develop/development-devices/trepn-profiler) which is used with the SnapDragon MDP, it costs 1000$. You will get the accuracy you need.

Comment: You can try using a tool called [Little Eye](http://www.littleeye.co). It's a $$$ product, but comes with a free trial.